# How to view my classes from asmx web service

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I have one ASMX webservice with C#. In this WebService I use some classes with properties. The Class is in the same namespace as Service1.asmx.

Code of my Web Service:

```
namespace NewWebService
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://www.MySite.net/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {     
        [WebMethod]
        public string GetUsers(string authenticatedToken) //out string error
        {

            //Extract from database the users...

            return Serialize(usersList);
        }
    ...
    }
}
```

Code of my class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace NewWebService
{
    public class Users
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        ...
    }
}
```

The question is: what must I make with my class to can view it in project where I added the webservice.

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't returning a collection of the User class instead of a string?

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: I serialize my list to string and then deserialize in List of Users.

Comment: Why do that? Just return `List<User>`?

Comment: Yes, but that is not my problem. The problem ist What I must do to view the class from web service in another project? Why I dont view all the classes from the webservice?

Comment: @wertyk: When you add a service reference from another project, the code generated by that service reference includes type definitions for the types exposed by that service.  (Note that these are *DTO* types, they do not include complex functionality.)

Comment: OK, try that solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning a `string`:

```
public string GetUsers(string authenticatedToken)
```

So the public definition for the web service is only going to expose information about a `string`.  There's nothing in the public interface regarding your class, so the web service doesn't advertise any information about your class.

Return a strongly-typed instance of the class.  Something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers(string authenticatedToken)
```

Then the generated web service code will include a definition of the type being returned, so consuming clients will be able to understand that type.  (And, for example, generate a local analog of that type if the consuming client includes code-generating capabilities.  It wouldn't be *the same* type from an assembly perspective, but across a service boundary that shouldn't really be a concern.)

Comment: The solution: 
@David: When you add a service reference from another project, the code generated by that service reference includes type definitions for the types exposed by that service. (Note that these are DTO types, they do not include complex functionality.)

Comment: Be sure to update the service reference as well, as the code Visual Studios generates won't necessarily be updated on a simple rebuild.